# Background img in full screen with css

Tags: html, css, background, wicket

I am trying to get `<div id="grid" wicket:id="grid">` to be a full screen image.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grid" wicket:id="grid" >

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java:**

```
WebMarkupContainer grid = new WebMarkupContainer("grid");
grid.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("style", "width:100%; height:100%;background:url(partimages/" + imageName + ") no-repeat;"));
add(grid);
```

Comment: any reason you are using java to add the styles?

Comment: I am very new to development with wicket and for this situation I gets the image name from database and it can be changed according to the parameter that the user sets on url, that is the only solution I found for wicket, thanks

Comment: ah ok, make sure `html` and `body` also have their heights set to 100% otherwise grid won't take any height.  You probably should update your version of jQuery too - 1.4 is very old, we're onto v2+ now or 1.11 if you still need ie8 support

Comment: Jquery 1.4 is the project standard so cannot change it. And I just have changed the html, body height:100% but it shows a very big part of image not all image on full screen.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `Wicket` (when using ajax) also contribues `jQuery` to the headers

Answer (score 1):

Your `DIV` is not as high as the screen (body), and your background is limited to the size of the `DIV`

One solution would be to set the 100% height on `HTML` and `BODY` too, as Pete suggested in his comment.

See this question for far more detail: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1575141/461499)

Answer (score 0):

You have tried "cover"? [w3c example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)

```
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: when I set just background-size:cover; it shows an empty screen if I set it with width:100%; height:100%; just sets the part of img on the full screen not set all img.  @Athair